# JavaScript delete confirm box

Tags: javascript

My function is something like this:

```
function delete(type, id){
    if(id){
        window.location.href = '/site/'+type+'/delete/'+id;
    }
}
```

I'm calling it like this:

```
onclick="delete('position', <?php echo $key;?>)
```

Where in the function should I put the Confirm option?

Comment: Better not use `delete` as function name.

Comment: what markup node is that onclick handler attached to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
function deleteIt(type, id)
{
    if(id && confirm('Are you sure you want to delete?'))
    {
        window.location.href = '/site/'+type+'/delete/'+id;
    }
}
```

Comment: It still won't show me a Confirm box. It just deletes without asking me.

Answer (score 0):

```
function delete(type, id)
{
    if(id && (confirm('Are you sure you want to delete?')))
    {
        window.location.href = '/site/'+type+'/delete/'+id;
    }
}
```